# Programatically displaying Calendar view with XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am adding a XsltListViewWebPart dynamically to an asp Panel. This code works except I cannot get the calendar view to display. Despite specifying the guid, a regular list view will appear (Even though the 'Calendar' view is selected on load). Any suggestions? ty

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Events"];
SPView view = oList.Views["Calendar"];    
XsltListViewWebPart lvwp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
lvwp.ListDisplayName = "Events";
lvwp.ViewFlags = SPViewFlags.Calendar;
lvwp.ViewId = Int32.Parse(view.BaseViewID);
lvwp.ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B");
pnlListVIew.Controls.Add(lvwp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem. The solution for me was to use Listviewwebpart and not Xsltlistviewwebpart. That is also What Sharepoint is doing behinhd the scene when you set à calendar view from the Gui.

Comment: It was a while ago, but I think is was using SP 2010 for this as SharePoint 2013, every List View Web Part is XSL or JSLink. Thanks for sharing though!